# Locking on map value

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization, locking

I want to synchronize access to a scoped resource (ex. user-specific resource) by having a map of locks (*i.e.* user ID to lock mapping).  I also don't want to keep that user-specific lock in memory if it isn't needed.  My "main" method creates 1000 threads and calls this method with the same key to simulate the concurrent access, and it fails at the first assertion.  The code only passes if I uncomment the `synchronized (SERVICE_CLASS_LOCK)` line, but I don't want to do that for reasons out of the scope of this question.  Any ideas?

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

import org.testng.Assert;

public class Issue
{
    private static final int THREAD_COUNT = 1000;
    private static final ConcurrentMap<String, Object> LOCKS = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    // This is just for example's sake. In reality this is a resource
    // related to the provided key (ex. user ID). This could be a database row,
    // File on disk, REST API call, etc.
    private static final AtomicBoolean SOME_SCOPED_RESOURCE = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private static final Object SERVICE_CLASS_LOCK = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
    {
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
        CompletionService<Boolean> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(threadPool);
        AtomicReference<Throwable> taskException = new AtomicReference<>();
        for (int currentThreadNumber = 0; currentThreadNumber < THREAD_COUNT; currentThreadNumber++)
        {
            final int taskNumber = currentThreadNumber;
            completionService.submit(() -> {
                try
                {
                    someTask("someKey", taskNumber);
                }
                catch (Throwable t)
                {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    taskException.set(t);
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
        for (int currentThreadNumber = 0; currentThreadNumber < THREAD_COUNT; currentThreadNumber++)
        {
            completionService.take();
        }
        threadPool.shutdownNow();
        if (taskException.get() != null)
        {
            throw taskException.get();
        }
    }

    public static void someTask(String key, int taskNumber)
    {
        AtomicBoolean shouldRemoveLock = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        Object newLock = new Object();
        Object previousLock = LOCKS.putIfAbsent(key, newLock);
        Object resourceSpecificLock = previousLock == null ? newLock : previousLock;
        shouldRemoveLock.set(previousLock == null);

        // No exceptions if I uncomment the following line
        // synchronized (SERVICE_CLASS_LOCK)
        {
            synchronized (resourceSpecificLock)
            {
                System.err.println(taskNumber + ": lock=" + resourceSpecificLock);
                Assert.assertFalse(SOME_SCOPED_RESOURCE.getAndSet(true), "failed for task " + taskNumber);
                System.err.println("did some work for task " + taskNumber);
                Assert.assertTrue(SOME_SCOPED_RESOURCE.getAndSet(false), "failed for task " + taskNumber);
            }
            // It also does not work if this block is moved to the end inside the synchronized
            // (resourceSpecificLock) block above, with no other changes.
            // So it seems the issue is related to not being able to remove the
            // lock at the right time.
            if (shouldRemoveLock.get())
            {
                System.err.println("removing resourceSpecificLock for task " + taskNumber);
                LOCKS.remove(key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A side note you can simply this:

```
Object newLock = new Object();
Object previousLock = LOCKS.putIfAbsent(key, newLock);
Object resourceSpecificLock = previousLock == null ? newLock : previousLock;
```

to just:

```
Object resourceSpecificLock = LOCKS.computeIfAbsent(key, v -> new Object());
```

Even with that change you will still have a *race-condition*. The problem is not on the Map of locks, but on the fact that there are multiple threads accessing the same resource

```
SOME_SHARED_RESOURCE
```

Even if the threads synchronize using a lock based on the Key, multiple threads can still change `SOME_SHARED_RESOURCE` (*i.e.,* threads that use different locks from different keys).

The race-condition is as follows:

1. Thread 1 of Key = ID1 calls `SOME_SHARED_RESOURCE.getAndSet(true)`
2. Before Thread 1 has the time to call `SOME_SHARED_RESOURCE.getAndSet(false)` a second Thread from a Key with a different ID (hence a different lock) calls `SOME_SHARED_RESOURCE.getAndSet(true)` and you got the Exception.

That is why when you use `synchronized (SOME_SHARED_RESOURCE)` it works, because there is not multiple threads calling `SOME_SHARED_RESOURCE`.

If you want to test the `Map` of locks, I suggest you to adapt your example to use a shared resource based on the Keys instead. In this way, you can test that threads with the same Key do not concurrently change the same Key-related data.

```
public class Issue
{
    private static final int THREAD_COUNT = 1000;
    private static final ConcurrentMap<String, Object> LOCKS = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static final ConcurrentMap <String, Boolean> SOME_SHARED_RESOURCE = new ConcurrentHashMap();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
    {
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
        CompletionService<Boolean> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(threadPool);
        AtomicReference<Throwable> taskException = new AtomicReference<>();
        for (int currentThreadNumber = 0; currentThreadNumber < THREAD_COUNT; currentThreadNumber++)
        {
            final int taskNumber = currentThreadNumber;
            completionService.submit(() -> {
                try
                {
                    String key = "someKey";
                    SOME_SHARED_RESOURCE.putIfAbsent(key, Boolean.TRUE);
                    someTask(key, taskNumber);
                }
                catch (Throwable t)
                {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    taskException.set(t);
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
        for (int currentThreadNumber = 0; currentThreadNumber < THREAD_COUNT; currentThreadNumber++)
        {
            completionService.take();
        }
        threadPool.shutdownNow();
        if (taskException.get() != null)
        {
            throw taskException.get();
        }
    }

    public static void someTask(String key, int taskNumber)
    {
        Object resourceSpecificLock = LOCKS.computeIfAbsent(key, v -> new Object());

            synchronized (resourceSpecificLock)
            {
                System.err.println(taskNumber + ": lock=" + resourceSpecificLock);
                if(!SOME_SHARED_RESOURCE.replace(key, Boolean.FALSE)){
                    throw new RuntimeException();
                }
                System.err.println("did some work for task " + taskNumber);
                if(SOME_SHARED_RESOURCE.replace(key, Boolean.TRUE)){
                    throw new RuntimeException();
                }
                LOCKS.remove(key);
            }
    }
}
```